# How do i get the change by oberving file with inotifywait

Tags: bash, scripts, inotify

I want to get the user name each time when its password is changed in 
/etc/shadow.
Here is my script:

```
while inotifywait -e attrib /etc/shadow; do
                 #edit user
                        while IFS=: read -r f1 f2
                           #get username for changed password
                        done < $file
         #end edit user
done
```

How can I easily do that?

Comment: And how will you know what has changed in `/etc/shadow`, if you can't compare `/etc/shadow` with anything?

Comment: Also, in second while loop where `$file` is initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show your last password change use `passwd`

```
passwd -S | awk '{print $3}'
```

or for a different username

```
sudo passwd -S user_name | awk '{print $3}'
```

Therefore you can loop over the usernames in `/etc/passwd` in your script and show the timestamps for each user, maybe for users with a ID >= 1000.

```
while inotifywait -e attrib /etc/shadow; do
    awk -F: '($3 >= 1000) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | xargs -I{} passwd -S {} | awk '{print $1,$3}'
done
```

To determine which items have changed exactly, you have to save the output of `awk …` and compare with the next start.

---

*Example*

```
% passwd -S | awk '{print $3}'
07/14/2015

% passwd
Changing password for aboettger.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully

% passwd -S | awk '{print $3}'
10/01/2015
```

or for a concrete user account

```
% sudo passwd -S root | awk '{print $3}'
05/29/2015
```

or for all users

```
% awk -F: '($3 >= 1000) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | xargs -I{} passwd -S {} | awk '{print $1,$3}'
passwd: You may not view or modify password information for nobody.
aboettger 10/01/2015
```

Comment: Nice. Note that you need to run all of the commands in the first part as root.

Comment: @A.B. wish it could return timestamp, but it is only date.